# Please rename the [rls] tag to [rust-language-server]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

The acronym RLS is ambiguous - and it's established that three-letter-tags are a bad idea.

[rls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rls) may mean either [row-level-security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/row-level-security) or [rust-language-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-language-server). Of the 44 questions where it has been applied, only 13 are also tagged as [rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust) - the rest actually are database questions. Let's clean them up and blacklist "rls".

Comment: I'd conjecture that questions about row-level security are questions that lean more towards the DBA side of things rather than the programmer side of things, since that speaks to a more administrative function rather than a programming function.

Comment: @Makoto Are you trying to suggest every question about rls is off-topic and should be asked at [dba.SE] instead?

Comment: It's just a conjecture.  It may depend on the DBMS on how it's implemented but this does sound more like something that a DBA-like role would be in charge of.

Comment: Seems reasonable to me, especially given the current wiki for [tag:rls] and the existence of the [tag:row-level-security] tag. I'd be happy to rename the [rls] tag to [rust-language-server] once the tag usage is disambiguated on main.

Comment: The [tag:row-level-security] tag has ~300 questions if it's off-topic/meets the burnination criteria/etc that would need to be a separate proposal/cleanup effort.

Comment: Questions about RLS can certainly be on topic for [so]. Some questions may be better™ on [dba.se], however, there's a decent amount of overlap for the 2 sites. If a user was asking, for example, for help on writing the `FUNCTION` for RLS (in SQL Server), then that would likely be more on-topic of [so].

Comment: There is also the (too) generic *"Language Server"* in [Language Server Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Server_Protocol). Are these two related or not?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yes, they are related - the [rust language server](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rls) does (or did) implement the [language server protocol](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The majority of usage of [rls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rls) was for [row-level-security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/row-level-security). I went ahead and retagged a bunch of stuff, apologies to anyone watching the [row-level-security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/row-level-security) tag (or those related). I didn't evaluate the questions beyond a cursory look and confirming their usage of RLS to mean row level security. Please feel free to review the recently active [row-level-security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/row-level-security) posts and handle anything that needs additional moderation.

One person also used [rls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rls) for "recursive least squares" (which has now been appropriately retagged as well).

I've renamed the tag to [rust-language-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-language-server) (preserving the wiki and wiki excerpt). I did not create any synonyms so [rls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rls) should no longer exist.

If you see the [rls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rls) tag reappear please [propose the tag be blacklisted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239192).